# How to change the users default language for GSuite via google api?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace

I am looking for a way to change the language for a single user for the complete GSuite.

For Gmail for example it would be [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateLanguage). However I would like to change the default language for the complete GSuite.

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two things:

1. As an admin, you cannot change the GSuite language for already existing users, you can only set-up a language for new users as decribed [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4594724?hl=en).
2. Unfortunately the implementation of the feature above (`Account settings > Profile > Language`) has not been implemented into the Admin SDK yet.

- Indeed, multiple features available in the Admin console have [not been implemented](https://issuetracker.google.com/36759558) into the API (yet).
- As for the language settings, currently it is not even possible to [retrieve](https://issuetracker.google.com/65724783) them via API, not to mention to change them.

Comment: and this setting applies for ALL new users in the account and cannot be set for one OU for example right?

Comment: It is an account-wide rather than domain-wide setting, so it cannot be performed for an OU.